# How to format a bilingual poetry book

Tags: books, poetry

I would like to write a bilingual poetry book (English-German) using LaTeX for PDF (Kindle Publishing).

Here it is how it should look like:

1. Title page with author name at the bottom;
2. Table of Content Page
3. Acknowledgement Page;
4. Page with a single quotation of a famous writer praising the book;
5. Preface Page;
6. One page with bilingual poems in two independent columns, line by line.

Does anybody know a LaTex poetry book that looks like that?
Does anybody know how to tackle the "problem"?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Personally, I'd prefer to see the original on the even page, an its translation on the next odd page.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming me. It is an English-German book and I think it would be nice to have both poems on the same page for immediate comparison effect. I have some 25 poems, which would amount to more than fifty pages or more. That would be a lot, wouldn't it?

Comment: Each verse is short enough? I thought that facing pages would be nice too, withou the problem of horizontal space

Comment: You can see the `parallel` or `paracol` package.

Comment: What do you mean by "facing pages"? Does that mean that the reader sees the original and its translation simultaneously upon reading the poems?

Comment: Yes, exactly$$.

Comment: Someone has already sent me very useful examples of how to format the book using using : \documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}           but I keep making silly mistakes. It is the second time I am trying to use LaTeX...

Comment: "Yes, exactly$$. – Bernard"   That seems to be a very good idea. Do you have some examples?

Comment: I wouldn't use the  `article` class for a book. The three commands you show are very general. Is there anything more useful?

Comment: Sorry for the double $, I forgot this site doesn't use MathJax. This being said don't have examples of sych a thing with LaTeX code,, but you should really take a look at the documentation of the packages I mentioned to see how they work.

Comment: Thanks a lot indeed. I am going to do that and see whether it works out for me. Best regards.

Comment: I agree with @Bernard to have the original and the translation on facing pages. I have a bilingual edition of Dante's Divina Comedia and it has this layout. It has also one language in black and the other one in a reddish ink. If you want to do that, you will have to load \usepackage{xcolor} also.

Comment: @Raoul Kessels: Of course, a  translation of short poems could be one above the other on the same page (It think  of limericks, such as in Edward Lear's *Nonsense songs ans stories*).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Bernard.

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gdzwghjpycsf

Comment: Well, Bernard, you have asked me whether there was anything more useful. I am including a link which shows a poem of mine as formatted by my kind and nice helper. The poem's title is Road Quarrel. There are some minor errors in the German version, but that is not relevant to the problem I have been discussing here. Now to the link: https://www.overleaf.com/read/gdzwghjpycsf         It is the way I thought the book would look great, but now you say that poems on facing pages do appeal more to the readers. Have you got a code for that? Why wouldn't you use "article" class for a book? Suggestion?

Comment: @AenigmaticeAntisigma -- Why not use `article` class for a book?  Although the requirements for poems are different, here's what distinguishes a regular book from an article,  Book has chapters; articles only sections.  For a book, table of contents, bibliography and index are treated as unnumbered chapters, with appropriate styling, not just run together as sections.  Running heads for a book are preset to chapter and section; for an article, author and title. Of course, all these can be changed, but why make trouble for yourself?

Comment: @AenigmaticeAntisigma I believe it is customary for the epigraph to precede the table of contents and for the preface to precede the acknowledgements. For more general information about arranging a book, I recommend consulting the Chicago Manual of Style. See sec. 1.4 for an outline of the parts of a book (https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part1/ch01/psec004.html).

Answer (score 2):

The Reledpar and Poemscol packages both have commands for setting parallel texts in just the way the poster requires.